why does Microsoft have both Synapse and ADF? Aren't both the same?
I'm new to Microsoft ETL world but I just don't understand why Microsoft has both Synapse and ADF.
Aren't both the same?
Or are they meant for different purposes?

Microsoft Synapse and Azure Data Factory (ADF) are two different services offered by Microsoft Azure, and while they both deal with data, they serve different purposes and have distinct functionalities.
Azure Data Factory (ADF):
Azure Data Factory is a cloud-based data integration service that allows you to create, schedule, and orchestrate data workflows at scale.
It's primarily used for data movement, data transformation, and data orchestration tasks.
ADF enables you to ingest data from various sources, transform it as needed, and load it into target data stores.
Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure SQL Data Warehouse):
Azure Synapse Analytics is a cloud-based analytics service that integrates big data and data warehousing capabilities.
It provides functionalities for data integration, enterprise data warehousing, and big data analytics.
Synapse Analytics can analyze large volumes of structured and unstructured data, perform complex queries, and derive insights from the data stored in various sources.
While both services deal with data, they serve different purposes within the data lifecycle:
Azure Data Factory focuses on the movement and transformation of data, enabling data pipelines and ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) workflows.
Azure Synapse Analytics, on the other hand, focuses on data analytics, providing capabilities for data warehousing, big data analytics, and real-time analytics.

Clear! Thanks a lot Jordan!

Just to add on top of what Jordan stated,
Azure Synapse Analytics can be considered superset over Azure data factory as it contains Data pipelines, Notebooks, Databases etc.
So ADF is just a subset as compared to synapse.
And there are comparable differences across data pipelines across both ADF and synapse like ADF supports SHIR sharing unlike synapse and ADF has support for airflow integration as well but 90% of features are similar across ADF and Synapse data pipelines
